# adding javascript file to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

I want to use javascript files in react js, I saw many answers where they told to add script src in index.html in this way :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    
  <title>React App</title>
  <script src="../src/app.js"></script>
  <script src="../src/helper.js"></script>
  <script src="../src/sort-algorthms.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="root"></div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

but this is not working, please anyone help .
even tried this - https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668

here is link to sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/trail-minipro-rxjz9?file=/public/index.html

Comment: What exactly is not working? Your sandbox seems to work at first glance

Comment: @charlietfl all is working except scripts.  This was simple project with html css n js. I managed to convert html into react. This is how it should work https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wk-l8mQt8nXo2snwqfs1jvpaBn_q1-tG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have to move your `js` files in the public folder. Update the path of the `js` files in the `index.html`, and it will work. But I see you are using `import`s in those files, you have to remove the `import`s in those files as it will not work in the `public` folder.

Comment: you can check this quick [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-carson-uc6u4?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Ejaz didnt worked. But thank you for giving your time :)

Comment: can you share the codesandbox link with your updated code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trail-minipro-rxjz9

Comment: you can try this - https://codesandbox.io/s/trail-minipro-forked-wdvji?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: `getComboA` function is not defined in your code, its a typo i think. you have to correct it